# Next.js middleware matcher to only match URLs with a capital letter

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I am trying to create a middleware in Next.js (v12.2) to convert URLs to be all lowercase. It's a safety net based on some odd inbound URLs coming in from external that we want to normalise. I cannot find a way of crafting a regular expression that includes both a negative lookahead (for paths like `_next/static`) and a positive test for `[A-Z]`.

I have modified the example in the Next.js docs to retain the exclusions of normal static files but also add a match for a capital letter `[A-Z]` somewhere in the path.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server"

const hasUpperCase = (string: string): boolean => {
  const uppercaseCharacters = /[A-Z]/g
  return uppercaseCharacters.test(string)
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest): NextResponse {
  if (hasUpperCase(request.nextUrl.pathname)) { // Double-check there's a capital
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`${request.url.toLocaleLowerCase()}`))
  }
  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon|site.).*(?:[A-Z]+).*)",
  ],
}
```

I would expect the middleware function to only fire in response to requests that meets BOTH conditions in the regex:

1. Doesn't match the prefixes defined in the negative lookahead
2. Contains a capital letter (eg `/path/to/Capital`).

I've tested the regex in [Regexr](https://regexr.com) and it works as expected, only matching a path where a capital is in the URL.
[An image demonstrating testing of this regular expression on Regexr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTs5H.png)

However, when deployed to Vercel my middleware function is called by any request that doesn't match that first non-capturing group, even if entirely lowercase. For example, a request for `/path/to/lowercase` is being matched, which I don't want.

I've now hit over a million Edge Middleware function requests on Vercel in days and am now being billed for unnecessary invocations of the function. What am I missing in my regex and how do I only fire the middleware function when there's a capital letter?

Could the issue be with having both a negative lookahead and a non-capturing group in the same regex?

Comment: Does it work locally, before you deploy it?

Comment: Yes. If I put a console log in my middleware function it's only logging on pages with capital letters.